# Is this Singleton alternative good?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm making a simple C++ wrapper for GNU readline, called Console. The GNU library is in C, and keeps a global state of currently registered functions that perform various tasks. For example, it allows the registration of global functions which perform autocompletion and other tasks.

At the same time, I would like this class to maintain a local state, containing for example a number of registered commands, current history and so on, which should be different between Console instances. Given that I am only allowed a single global state below, I can only allow a single Console at any given time.

However, making the Console a Singleton would imply global accessibility. Thus, if a part of the code is using the Console with certain settings, it would not be able to assume that the settings and state it has setup for the Console will remain unchanged, as any other part of the code will have access to the Singleton Console.

Since I would not like that, as I would like to keep code managing a particular I/O close together, I am thinking that making this class a Singleton is not a good idea. My initial solution for this was something along the lines of:

```
class Console {
    public:
        Console() { 
            if ( instanced_ ) throw std::runtime_error("Console already instanced");
            instanced_ = true;
        }
        static bool exists() { return instanced_; }
    private:
        static bool instanced_ /* = false */;
}
```

My current new solution, as pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614144/1356926), is to reset the global settings of the library every time a Console is accessed, instead of limiting the amount of Console instances at a time. Is there any other option that I should be aware of?

Comment: You want to make a Singleton without making a Singleton?  I don't follow the logic...  I guess you mean you're avoiding one of many possible ways to construct a Singleton?

Comment: "I wanted to avoid the usage of the Singleton pattern, as I don't really think that making this class available globally and publicly is a good idea" - The Singleton pattern is exactly what you **are** looking for.  It is a design pattern that fits your needs perfectly.  When you need to use a hammer, don't ask how you can use a screwdriver as a hammer ... use the hammer.

Comment: from Wikipedia: *In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object.* - which is what you are describing as what you want. Could you explain why you do not want to follow the singleton pattern here?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz a `public Console` would be equally global, no?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : It's wrapping a library that has a single set of global state.  It implies global access because there's no getting around the fact it's global access.

Comment: @Default What? Do you mean public constructor? No, public constructor doesn't mean global access. Public variable? Perhaps, but he didn't say he wants it as a public member variable.

Comment: @JoeZ If you choose to only use his class and not the underlying implementation, you can effectively remove global access to the console. Which is exactly why Singleton doesn't necessarily fit here.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Precisely. In addition the library is only linked in the implementation, so whoever was including my header wouldn't even know that I'm using this particular library.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz : Actually, this really seems like a form of mutex problem:  Only one client can have its state in `readline` at a time.  If the program is single threaded, then you don't really even need a mutex.  If `readline` allows swapping state in and out, then there's no reason to limit `Console` to a single instance.  You just need to keep track as to whether your state needs to be swapped in.  See my updated answer below.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm sorry if I somehow offended you, I fail to see the need for all caps lock. I guess asking for more information is frowned upon here? Anyway, I fail to see the difference between holding a single object in memory (which the OP would need to avoid creating several Consoles) and just holding a single Console.. I fail to understand the logic behind this decision. Is it wrong to ask for clarification then?

Comment: @Default The difference is precisely what I put in my all-caps statement. I guess its use wasn't really unwarranted, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have private `static` members that wrap the `readline` C interface, and make all instances of your class coordinate with that single, static instance under the hood.  If you think of your class as just a method wrapper around `readline` and have no state in the class, there's no reason to make the class itself a Singleton.

That is, if you have two parts of your program do this:

```
 Console fred; 
 string input = fred.readline();
```

and:

```
 Console barney;
 string input = barney.readline();
```

there's no real harm so long as `Console` itself has no non-static state.  The alternative would be to pass the one `Console` instance around, or have a global function that returns you that instance, but it gains you nothing.

The fact of the matter is that `readline` itself forces you into a single instance of global state shared by everyone, and you're just putting an object wrapper around it.

---

**EDIT**:  From your updated question, it sounds like what you're really going for is a form of mutual exclusion here, where there is only one currently-active `Console` client at a time, as opposed to "exactly one `Console` over the life of the program."

One thing you could consider doing is this:  Build your class to have a mixture of `static` and non-`static` state.  The `static` state would keep track of the last instance of `Console` to interact with `libreadline`.

Then, in each of your methods that need to interact with `libreadline`, you could call a private method that ensures that *this* particular instance of `Console` has its state swapped into `libreadline` ahead of the call.

I'm suggesting something like this:

```
class Console 
{
    static Console *current;

    void make_current(void)
    {
        if (current == this)
            return;

        if (current)
            current->save_state();

        // copy our state into libreadline here, and then make us current
        ...
        current = this;
    } 

    void save_state()
    {
        // copy our state out of libreadline here, and then relinquish current
        ...
        current = nullptr;
    }

public:

    void method_foo()  // this method interacts with libreadline
    {
        make_current();
        // ...
    }

    void method_bar()  // this method does not interact with libreadline
    {                  // no calls to make_current required
    }

    ~Console()
    {
        // If we're current when we're being destroyed, relinquish
        // current.  We don't need to save anything, as we're going away.
        if (current == this)
            current = nullptr;
    }
};

static Console::current = nullptr; // make sure current initializes to nullptr
```

Comment: The problem is that I do have a state, since clients can add commands that do things and the class registers those with the library and gives autocomplete facilities for them.

Comment: @Svalorzen : What I'm saying is that `class Console` doesn't have that state, `libreadline` does.  Controlling the number of instances of `class Console` doesn't change the fundamental nature of `libreadline`.

Comment: @Svalorzen : I just read your update.  It sounds like you're trying to get just "one instance at a time" as opposed to "one instance over the life of the program" as a form of mutual exclusion.  You could do that without true mutual exclusion.  I'll edit my answer above to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Svalorzen : What do you think of the mediated access approach above?

Comment: It's probably what I am looking for. If nothing else comes up I'll accept this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception seems a bit harsh. Why not have a pricate constructor and initialize the `Console` the first time it's requested and then return that instance afterwards.

Comment: Well I am providing a method to check whether there's an instance already. Also I'm not sure how what you are proposing will work.. Wouldn't that be a Singleton?

Comment: By throwing an exception in the construtor you've effectivly created a singleton. Also, this can only be enforced at runtime when someone tries to instanciate an instance of your class. Why not just go for a regular Singleton in the first place?

Comment: Because a singleton is globally accessible, and the class does keep an internal state of commands that have been added to it, which would need to be checked wherever the singleton is used. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I should say more about this class, even though I was only
>   looking for a good method of instantiating it. It has a state, and
>   clients can register commands which are also autocompleted. If I
>   create a new instance, for example, it would have no commands but the
>   default ones. Also, during construction also the client can set a
>   bunch of options of the library.
>
> Using a singleton would mean that a new user should have to first
>   remove all existing commands, but then it can't know if somebody else
>   is still using it. Thus I wanted to avoid that.

That description leads me to believe you are over-thinking this problem.  If each user is to have their own instance of `Console`, then you tie a single instance of `Console` to a `User` by having a `Console` member variable within your `User` class.  With only 1 member variable of the type, you will only ever have one instance per user.

Your initial description indicated you wanted a single instance for the life of your program, which would lead you to use the Singleton pattern (as that is what it does).  With your desire to have 1 instance per user, it is a simple matter of encapsulation.

Comment: The problem is that the library has for example global pointers to the functions used to provide autocomplete options. When a single Console is created, the pointers are set to functions that then examine the internal state of the Console instance, and thus another Console cannot be created. I could make the class more complex and set those functions to redirecters based on the instance that is currently being used, but that is way more work than I planned and I just wanted to avoid simple screw-ups.

Comment: You stated that "if another user logs in, they must clear the console first" - implying that multiple users can be logged in simultaneously.  If that is not the case (that is, only 1 user can be logged in, and there will only ever be 1 instance of `Console`), then the Singleton pattern is the direction you should go, and would simply need to clear its state when a user logs in.